# Reverse stacked bar order

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm creating a stacked bar chart using ggplot like this:

```
plot_df <- df[!is.na(df$levels), ] 
ggplot(plot_df, aes(group)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = levels), position = "fill")
```

Which gives me something like this:

[image]

How do I reverse the order the stacked bars themselves, so that level 1 is at the bottom, and level 5 is at the top of each bar?

I've seen a number of questions on this (e.g. [How to control ordering of stacked bar chart using identity on ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2)) and the common solution seems to be to reorder the dataframe by that level as that what ggplot is using the determine the order

So I've tried reordering using dplyr:

`plot_df <- df[!is.na(df$levels), ] %>% arrange(desc(levels))`

However, the plot comes out the same. It also doesn't seem to make a difference whether I arrange by ascending or descending order

Here is a reproducible example:

```
group <- c(1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4)
levels <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","5","5","5","5","1","1","1","1")
plot_df <- data.frame(group, levels)

ggplot(plot_df, aes(group)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = levels), position = "fill")
```

Comment: The order of the observations makes no sense, but the order of the factor levels does. Also, reprex.

Comment: yes, I have also tried changing the factor level order with `levels(plot_df$levels) <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")` (and the reverse order) but it doesn't change the graph order

Comment: Also added an example of the data

Comment: `plot_df %>% mutate(levels = factor(levels, levels = 5:1)) %>% ggplot(aes(group, fill = levels)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")` or just `ggplot(plot_df, aes(group)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = levels), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE))`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

[The release notes of `ggplot2` version 2.2.0 on *Stacking bars* suggest](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/releases/ggplot2-2.2.0.html#stacking-bars):

> If you want to stack in the opposite order, try `forcats::fct_rev()`

```
library(ggplot2)   # version 2.2.1 used    
plot_df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 6),
                      levels = factor(c(rep(1:5, each = 4), rep(1, 4))))
ggplot(plot_df, aes(group, fill = forcats::fct_rev(levels))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image: Reverse levels]

This is the **original plot**:

```
ggplot(plot_df, aes(group, fill = levels)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image: Original plot]

Or, using `position_fill(reverse = TRUE)` as suggested by [alistaire in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710056/r-ggplot-reverse-stacked-bar-order/42713157#comment72542092_42710056):

```
ggplot(plot_df, aes(group, fill = levels)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Note that the levels (colors) in the legend is not in the same order as in the stacked bars.

Comment: ```position_fill(reverse = TRUE)``` normalizes bars, use `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` if you don't want to normalize bars.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to reorder the factor as such, assuming the factor is called "levels":
levels = ordered(levels, levels=c(5,4,3,2,1)).
for more info: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/