# ggplot2 stacked bar, put NA on top

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710056/reverse-stacked-bar-order/42713157) had lots of great information about ordering bar sections in a stacked bar chart. After futzing with various alternatives, and getting mostly the order I want, NA keeps showing up on the bottom of the stack, which I don't like.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, fill=forcats::fct_rev(factor(able, levels=rev(likely))))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 0), 
        plot.margin = margin(10, 40, 10, 10))
```

[image]

The NAs on the x axis are at the end, which is great. And it's probably great in general to put NAs at the end. But with stacked bars, I consider the start to be the bottom and the end to be the top (because the stuff on the bottom is easier to compare.)

(A Marimekko chart would probably be better, but I gave up after a while of trying to get ggmosaic and various other things to work.)

**Edit**: I found some code that I modified to make the Marimekko chart (would like to give credit, but lost track of where I found it.) It does put the NAs at the top.

[image]

```
df %>%
group_by(satisfied, time) %>%
summarise(n = n()) %>%
mutate(x.width = sum(n)) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=satisfied, y=n)) +
geom_col(aes(width=x.width, fill=time),
         colour = "white", size=2, position=position_fill(reverse = T)) +
geom_text(aes(label=n),
           position=position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
facet_grid(~ satisfied, space = 'free', scales='free', switch='x') +
#scale_x_discrete(name="a") +
scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      strip.text = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0),
      strip.background = element_blank(),
      panel.spacing = unit(0,'pt'))
```

Serialized data at @z-lin's request:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(explanatory = c(8L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 9L, NA, 
5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 2L, NA, 6L, 
NA, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 13L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 7L, 1L, NA, 12L, 13L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 7L, NA, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 6L, 13L, 4L, NA, 2L, 
7L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 7L, 
NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 7L, 5L, 5L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 13L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 5L, 
11L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 
NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 9L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 
4L, 1L, 12L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 12L, NA, 4L, 2L, 11L, NA, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 6L, NA, 12L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 1L, 6L, 8L, NA, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, NA, 12L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 13L, NA, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 
11L, 12L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 6L, 9L, 2L, 1L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L, 6L, 
5L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 11L, 4L, 9L, NA, 12L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, NA, 10L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
6L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 13L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 3L, NA, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 13L, 13L, NA, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 8L), response = c(3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 
4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 
5L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L), time = structure(c(8L, 
3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 9L, NA, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 2L, NA, 6L, NA, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 7L, 
1L, NA, 12L, 13L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 7L, NA, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
3L, 13L, 6L, 13L, 4L, NA, 2L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 
13L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, NA, 7L, 
5L, 5L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, 3L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 
13L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 12L, 9L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 6L, NA, NA, 
NA, 4L, 12L, NA, 4L, 2L, 11L, NA, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 6L, NA, 
12L, 3L, 2L, 4L, NA, 1L, 6L, 8L, NA, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, NA, 4L, 
NA, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, NA, 4L, NA, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, NA, 12L, 
2L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 13L, NA, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, 11L, 12L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 
6L, 9L, 2L, 1L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
NA, 11L, 4L, 9L, NA, 12L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 5L, NA, 10L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 13L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
4L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 3L, NA, 2L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
2L, 13L, 13L, NA, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L), .Label = c("0-15 minutes", 
"15-30 minutes", "30-45 minutes", "45-60 minutes (1 hour)", "60 minutes (1 hour) - 75 minutes", 
"75-90 minutes", "90-105 minutes", "105-120 minutes (2 hours)", 
"120 minutes (2 hours) - 135 minutes", "135-150 minutes", "150-165 minutes", 
"165-180 minutes (3 hours)", "More than 3 hours"), class = "factor"), 
    able = c("Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", NA, 
    "Agree", NA, "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", NA, NA, NA, 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", NA, NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", NA, NA, "Agree", 
    "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", NA, "Strongly Agree", 
    NA, NA, "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", NA, "Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    NA, "Strongly Agree", NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Disagree", NA, "Agree", NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", NA, "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", "Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    NA, "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", NA, "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly Agree", NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Agree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree")), row.names = c(NA, 
-437L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `fill = factor(able, levels = c("NA", likely))` or `fill = factor(able, levels = c(likely, "NA"))`

Comment: Yeah, did that. Doesn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: Do you need your NA values to be `NA`? If not, you could replace them with the factor level `'NA'` and order them like any other factor

Comment: That's true. ggplot wouldn't automatically make them gray for me, though.

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(df)` in your question? It would be easier to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Do you think I should change the question/title so the answer I'm asking for is the Marimekko chart? I might have the same NA ordering problem with that, but the Marimekko chart would be a bigger help than just fixing the NA placement.

Comment: @Sigfried It's probably better to make a new question about that and either close this one or leave it open in case someone has a better answer than us

Comment: Well, I got the Marimekko thing working anyway and went ahead and appended it to the question since it also puts the NAs at top. But I'll leave the question, since the comments and stuff may be able to help someone struggling with similar problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that `factor()` excludes `NA` by default; you have to override the default.

This is plotting the `NA`s on top:

```
likely <- c(NA, "Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", 
            "Agree", "Strongly Agree") 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, fill = factor(able, levels = likely, exclude = NULL)
)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 0),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 40, 10, 10))
```

[image]

Additionally, the `NA` can also be moved to the top of the legend:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, fill = factor(able, levels = likely, exclude = NULL)
)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 0),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 40, 10, 10)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = likely)
```

[image]