# Changing Order of Stacked Geom_Bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm finalizing a graph and hoping to change the order of two segments of my stacked bar graph.

[image: Current Stacked Bar Chart]

I have tried both the forcats::fct_rev() solution as offered in documentation and [Reverse stacked bar order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710056/reverse-stacked-bar-order) as well as position_fill(reverse = TRUE) in my geom_bar argument.

```
Simplified code:
plot2<-ggplot(r_4,aes(x=V1,y=V3,fill=V2))+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

```
Data:
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Reagan", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Case-Based", "Term-Based"
    ), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.36", 
    "0.64"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like the smaller piece ("Term-Based") on the left and the larger piece ("Case-Based") on the right.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can convert it to `factor` with levels specified int he order

Comment: I think you want `position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` in `geom_bar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: change V3, not V2

As akrun commented, change factor levels, then it should work:

```
r_4$V3 <- factor(c("0.36", "0.64"))

plot2<-ggplot(r_4,aes(x=V1,y=V3,fill=V2))+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried this (and just tried again). It flips the coloring, but not the actual area. I even manually changed the dataset, too.

Comment: Just got it to work. I had to reorder V3 rather than V2. Thanks for the jumpstart.