# Change order for factor in grouped-bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reverse

I have the following code:

```
figg4 <- lala4 %>% gather(key, value, -Species_Name) %>%  
  mutate (Species_Name = factor(Species_Name, 
levels=c('Dasyprocta punctata',
'Cuniculus paca','Large Rats',
 'Heteromys unknown', 'Sciurus variegatoides',
 'Sciurus granatensis','Dasypus novemcinctus',
'Didelphis marsupialis',  'Philander opossum',
'Metachirus nudicaudatus', 'Nasua narica',
 'Procyon lotor', 'Eira barbara',
'Galictis vittata', 'Leopardus pardalis'))) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=Species_Name, y=value, 
             fill=key)) + coord_flip() + geom_col (position = "stack") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + bbc_style() +
  labs(title = "Species occupancy by Site Type")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#333333","#1380A1", "#FAAB18"))
```

I get bar graph which is listing the names in the reverse order, I want to make them appear in the order that I have written the levels in... how do I do so?

I tried using fct_reorder from forcats by adding the following code

```
mutate(name = fct_reorder(Species_Name, desc(value)))
```

But that did not change the order.
I am quite new to r and not sure of how to do this. Would be grateful for any help

Here is dput output for the source:

> dput(lala4)
>   structure(list(Species_Name = structure(c(9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
>   19L, 22L, 27L, 46L, 41L, 42L, 10L, 15L, 32L, 33L, 24L), .Label = c("Buteo platypterus", 
>   "Canis latrans", "Cathartes aura", "Catharus unknown", "Catharus ustulatus", 
>   "Cebus capucinus", "Chordeiles unknown", "Conepatus semistriatus", 
>   "Crax rubra", "Crypturellus cinnamomeus", "Cuniculus paca", "Dasyprocta punctata", 
>   "Dasypus novemcinctus", "Didelphis marsupialis", "Eira barbara", 
>   "Galictis vittata", "Geotrygon montana", "Geotrygon violacea", 
>   "Heteromys unknown", "Holcosus quadrilineatus", "Large Rats", 
>   "Leopardus pardalis", "Leopardus wiedii", "Leptotila unknown", 
>   "Melozone unknown", "Metachirus nudicaudatus", "Nasua narica", 
>   "Odocoileus virginianus", "Panthera onca", "Parkesia noveboracensis", 
>   "Pecari tajacu", "Penelopina nigra", "Philander opossum", "Piaya cayana", 
>   "Procyon lotor", "Puma concolor", "Puma yagouaroundi", "Sciurus granatensis", 
>   "Sciurus variegatoides", "Setophaga unknown", "Sylvilagus sp ", 
>   "Tamandua mexicana", "Tapirus bairdii", "Tayassu pecari", "Tigrisoma fasciatum", 
>   "Tinamus major"), class = "factor"), `Forest Area (<5ha)` = c(0.067307692, 
>   0.134615385, 0.173076923, 0.144230769, 0.019230769, 0.086538462, 
>   0.192307692, 0.009615385, 0.163461538, 0.038461538, 0, 0.019230769, 
>   0, 0.163461538, 0.153846154), `Forest Area (5-27ha)` = c(0.067307692, 
>   0.317307692, 0.269230769, 0.096153846, 0.038461538, 0.105769231, 
>   0.192307692, 0.115384615, 0.134615385, 0.057692308, 0, 0.096153846, 
>   0, 0.076923077, 0.173076923), `Forest Area (>350ha)` = c(0.163461538, 
>   0.384615385, 0.278846154, 0.201923077, 0.105769231, 0.067307692, 
>   0.144230769, 0.298076923, 0.028846154, 0.048076923, 0.086538462, 
>   0.038461538, 0.019230769, 0.028846154, 0.125)), row.names = c(NA, 
>   15L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: How about: `ggplot(aes(x=forcats::fct_rev(Species_Name)...`?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and some output

Comment: Perhaps, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713157/3817004 gives some hints.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine the factor as an ordered factor first.

Try just fixing the code where you define the factor by adding

```
ordered = TRUE
```

This should probably work:

```
figg4 <- lala4 %>% gather(key, value, -Species_Name) %>%  
  mutate (Species_Name = factor(Species_Name, 
levels=c('Dasyprocta punctata',
'Cuniculus paca','Large Rats',
 'Heteromys unknown', 'Sciurus variegatoides',
 'Sciurus granatensis','Dasypus novemcinctus',
'Didelphis marsupialis',  'Philander opossum',
'Metachirus nudicaudatus', 'Nasua narica',
 'Procyon lotor', 'Eira barbara',
'Galictis vittata', 'Leopardus pardalis'), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=Species_Name, y=value, 
             fill=key)) + coord_flip() + geom_col (position = "stack") +
theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + bbc_style() +
  labs(title = "Species occupancy by Site Type")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#333333","#1380A1", "#FAAB18"))
```

I can't run it because I don't have the `lala4` data to test though.

Comment: Thank you Alison, I did try it but it dint work. I instead manually created a reverse order and added that reversed order --- which gave me the graph in the order that I wanted it to be but just in case you were interested I added the dput output of the dataframe.

Comment: Interesting,  I'm not sure about the dput.  Perhaps if you defined Species_Name as an ordered factor in the lala4 data before you call ggplot it might work.  Anyway, you found a solution to your problem. Perhaps someone else knows why.  It's much easier for people to help if you provide a reproducable example - then people can test it themselves and provide you with a clear solution. Look at the note by @camille above.

Comment: Will do that Alison :)! Thank you for the response.